# UICollectionView displaying less cells than dataSource.count

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have 2 `UICollectionViewControllers` with (as far as I can tell) identical code and storyboard settings.  This app uses the Pinterest SDK so I am downloading boards and pins 25 at a time.

The first `CollectionViewController` dataSource (using 80 boards for example), will display 80 boards.  The second `CollectionViewController` (using 80 pins for example) will only display 25 pins.

I added a statement of `print(indexPath.row)` in each's `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

The correctly operating CVC prints 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 etc.

The 2nd CVC prints 1,2,3,4,5 then 1,2,3,4,5 1,2,3,4,5 etc.

Can anyone figure out what's going on?  EDIT:  the 2nd CVC's code below, I've stripped out all non-relevant code:

```
class PinCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    //TODO: V2.0  FIND (1) duplicate pins (2) pins with out descriptions

    var pins = [PDKPin]()
    var imageArray = [UIImage]()
    var boardID = String()
    var boardName = String()
    var fetchingMore = false
    var currentResponseObject =  PDKResponseObject()
    var activityIndicatorView: ActivityIndicatorView!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? PinterestLayout {
            layout.delegate = self
        }

        getFirstPinsAndImages()


    }


    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.pins.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PinCollectionViewCell

        cell.pinText?.text = self.pins[indexPath.row].descriptionText
        cell.pinImage?.pin_updateWithProgress = true


        if let pinImageURL = self.pins[indexPath.row].largestImage().url {

            cell.pinImage?.pin_setImageFromURL(pinImageURL)


        }


              return cell
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


            getRestOfPinsAndImages()

    }
     func loadImages(imageURLs: [NSURL], completion: [(url:NSURL, image:UIImage?)] -> Void) {

        var downloads = imageURLs.count
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        var images = [(url:NSURL, image:UIImage?)]()

        for url in imageURLs {

            let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, reponse, error) in

                var image:UIImage?
                if let data = data {
                    image = UIImage(data: data)
                }

                dispatch_sync(blocksDispatchQueue) {
                    //print("dispatch_Sync inside loadImages")
                    images.append((url:url, image:image))
                    downloads--
                }

                if downloads == 0 {

                    self.allImagesLoaded = true
                    // Alternative way of completing to ensure run on main thread
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { completion(images) }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }


    }

    func getFirstPinsAndImages() {


        PDKClient.sharedInstance().getBoardPins(boardID, fields: ["id", "image", "note", "link"], withSuccess: { (responseObject :PDKResponseObject!) -> Void in

            self.currentResponseObject = responseObject

            guard let pinsAsPDKPin = responseObject.pins() as? [PDKPin] else {
                                return
            }

            self.pins = pinsAsPDKPin


            if let imageURLs = (pinsAsPDKPin.map { $0.largestImage().url }) as? [NSURL] {


                //get images
                self.loadImages(imageURLs, completion: {results in
                    // scan through results for the images found and
                    // add to array of images to display
                    for r in results {
                        if let image = r.image {
                            self.imageArray.append(image)
                        }
                    }
                })
            }


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                self.collectionView?.reloadData()

            })



            })  { (err :NSError!) -> Void in
                print("error NSError: \(err)")
        }



    }





    func getRestOfPinsAndImages() {




            if self.fetchingMore == false && self.currentResponseObject.hasNext()  {


                self.fetchingMore = true

                self.currentResponseObject.loadNextWithSuccess({ (nextResponseObject :PDKResponseObject!) -> Void in


                    self.fetchingMore = false
                    self.currentResponseObject = nextResponseObject

                    guard let pinsAsPDKPin = nextResponseObject.pins() as? [PDKPin] else { return }



                    for pin in pinsAsPDKPin {
                        self.pins.append(pin)
                    }

                    if let imageURLs = (pinsAsPDKPin.map { $0.largestImage().url }) as? [NSURL] {

                        self.loadImages(imageURLs, completion: {results in
                            // scan through results for the images found and
                            // add to array of images to display
                            for r in results {
                                if let image = r.image {
                                    self.imageArray.append(image)
                                }
                            }



                        })
                    }

                    if !self.currentResponseObject.hasNext() {

                    } else {
                        self.getRestOfPinsAndImages()
                    }

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                        self.collectionView?.reloadData()

                    })

                    }) { (err :NSError!) -> Void in
                        print("error NSError: \(err)")
                }

            }
        }




}

extension PinCollectionViewController : PinterestLayoutDelegate {
    // 1
    func collectionView(collectionView:UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath,
        withWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
            var photo = UIImage()
            if allImagesLoaded {
                photo = imageArray[indexPath.item]
            } else { photo = UIImage(named: "testPic")!}


            let boundingRect =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))
            let rect  = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(photo.size, boundingRect)
            return rect.size.height
    }

    // 2
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        heightForAnnotationAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, withWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
            var photo = UIImage()
            if allImagesLoaded {
                photo = imageArray[indexPath.item]
            } else { photo = UIImage(named: "testPic")!}

            let annotationPadding = CGFloat(4)
            let annotationHeaderHeight = CGFloat(17)
            let font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 10)!
            let commentHeight = CGFloat(10.0)
            let height = annotationPadding + annotationHeaderHeight + commentHeight + annotationPadding
            return height
    }
}
```

Comment: It's going to be hard for anyone to comment without you posting the code.

Comment: this sounds like your numberOfSections method is returning a value greater than 1. so it's showing 5 items in each section, but can't really help without seeing the methods you are using to populate the view.

Comment: Thanks guys, it's a large class so I tried to strip out everything that isn't related to the dataSource

Answer (score 0):

Just give us more details.
I think you gave us not enough information.

Try to create new project, and code simple UIImageView,
and launch it to iPhone 5s, 6, 6s.

If it is ok, then your project has some problem.
In this case, you have to gave us more information.